# Assign values from one Mysql table column to another Mysql table column

Tags: mysql

Say I have one MySQL schema named `srvconfig` with a table named `tbl_cfg` with following fields:

- `cfg_id`
- `sfg_srv_name`
- `cfg_srv_ip`
- `cfg_srv_port`
- `cfg_srv_desc`

There is another schema called `customer` with a table named `lcl_cfg` with following fields:

- `cust_id`
- `cust_info`
- `assigned_srv_id`
- `cust_serv`

In the schema called `customer` in `lcl_cfg.assigned_srv` 
I need to assign the value of `cfg_id` (which is the ID of the server from the schema `srvconfig.tbl_cfg.cfg.id`)

Can I achieve this using phpMyAdmin or do I need to do it with a PHP script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
update customer.lcl_cfg as t1 inner join srvconfig.tbl_cfg as t2 
on t1.cfg_id=t2.cfg_id
set t1.assigned_srv =t2.cfg_id
```

Comment: the Query works fine, but i am unable to see the value from srvconfig.tbl_cfg.cfg_id in the target table customer.lcl_cfg.assigned_srv